# Handle error when passing a wrong type argument to a command

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I'm want to treat the case when someone execute the "c" command on discord and passes a non-existent role as argument. I get the following error log:

```
@bot.command()
# Send DM to people that have the role
async def c(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, dm):
    try:
        for members in role.members:
            await members.create_dm.send(f'Massage from {ctx.author.display.name}: {dm}')
            print('Message sent to a member')
    except RoleNotFound:
        print('Role not found')
```

```
Ignoring exception in command c:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 635, in convert
    raise RoleNotFound(argument)
```

So, i thought treating it using `try/except`, but the error occours before it enters the `try`block.

PS: I don't want to prevent the error, but handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an error handler for this yourself, you can do this in a different way and have to go via `commands.YourError`. To use it you do not need to import something else but build your own "function" and re-structure your code.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.command()
# Send DM to people that have the role
async def c(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, dm):
    for members in role.members:
        await members.create_dm.send(f'Massage from {ctx.author.display.name}: {dm}')
        print('Message sent to a member')

@c.error
async def dm_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.RoleNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Role not found")
```

You can also build in more errors but can't use `except` as you wanted to do that first because you can just use it for `AttributeError` or `SyntaxError` or something similar.